# Set a child node as parent node in jquery TreeTable plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, parent-child, treetable

I am using the jQuery Treetable plugin from [this link](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/)

I am using the advanced example wherein i can drag and drop the child nodes from one parent to another. However, I am looking for a way in which I can set a child node as the parent node (i.e. I can drag the child node and drop it as a parent node). This plugin uses jQuery UI's draggable and droppable events.

Basically, I want any node (irrespective of whether it is a parent node or a child node) to be dragged and dropped anywhere in the treetable.

Does anyone has a workaround for this ?